# How to run protractor config file from browser's console

Tags: angularjs, browser, protractor

I would like to know how can we run a file from the browser' console. I have to run the protractor config file that we usually run from the terminal with the command

```
   ~  protractor config.js
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why do you need this, the motivation behind the question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about how to do this, but if you goal is to run the tests from the browser you ran that command in, my understanding is it won't work. Protractor will use selenium to spin up a new browser, and it can't grab any currently running if I remember correctly.

From the Chrome console in particular, I'm not sure if you have access to run other programs:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console